# How to address all events in global.asax file when we work with ASP.NET Core Middleware

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

here is the list of major events in global.asax file. suppose when we write code for each event in global.asax file to handle situation and when we will work with ASP.NET Core Middleware then tell me how to address each event code in ASP.NET Core Middleware. please come with a sample code to address all events in ASP.NET Core Middleware.

**Application_Init:**

> Fired when an application initializes or is first called. It is
>   invoked for all HttpApplication object instances.

**Application_Disposed:**

> Fired just before an application is destroyed. This is the ideal
>   location for cleaning up previously used resources.

**Application_Error:**

> Fired when an unhandled exception is encountered within the
>   application.

**Application_Start:**

> Fired when the first instance of the HttpApplication class is created.
>   It allows you to create objects that are accessible by all
>   HttpApplication instances.

**Application_End:**

> Fired when the last instance of an HttpApplication class is destroyed.
>   It is fired only once during an application's lifetime.

**Application_BeginRequest:**

> Fired when an application request is received. It is the first event
>   fired for a request, which is often a page request (URL) that a user
>   enters.

**Application_EndRequest:**

> The last event fired for an application request.

**Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute:**

> Fired before the ASP.NET page framework begins executing an event
>   handler like a page or Web service.

**Application_PostRequestHandlerExecute:**

> Fired when the ASP.NET page framework has finished executing an event
>   handler.

**Applcation_PreSendRequestHeaders:**

> Fired before the ASP.NET page framework sends HTTP headers to a
>   requesting client (browser).

**Application_PreSendContent:**

> Fired before the ASP.NET page framework send content to a requesting
>   client (browser).

**Application_AcquireRequestState:**

> Fired when the ASP.NET page framework gets the current state (Session
>   state) related to the current request.

**Application_ReleaseRequestState:**

> Fired when the ASP.NET page framework completes execution of all event
>   handlers. This results in all state modules to save their current
>   state data.

**Application_ResolveRequestCache:**

> Fired when the ASP.NET page framework completes an authorization
>   request. It allows caching modules to serve the request from the
>   cache, thus bypassing handler execution.

**Application_UpdateRequestCache:**

> Fired when the ASP.NET page framework completes handler execution to
>   allow caching modules to store responses to be used to handle
>   subsequent requests.

**Application_AuthenticateRequest:**

> Fired when the security module has established the current user's
>   identity as valid. At this point, the user's credentials have been
>   validated.

**Application_AuthorizeRequest:**

> Fired when the security module has verified that a user can access
>   resources.

**Session_Start:**

> Fired when a new user visits the application Web site.

**Session_End:**

> Fired when a user's session times out, ends, or they leave the
>   application Web site.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Regarding session in ASP.NET Core**

Classic ASP.NET includes a couple of session-related events: Session_Start and Session_End, which you can access via global.asax in order to execute code. In ASP.NET Core 1.0 , you can query the session collection using middleware to establish if a session has already been established to replicate the Session_Start event, but there are no plans to introduce an equivalent to Session_End.

Since one of the driving forces behind ASP.NET Core 1.0 is "cloud-readiness", the focus on session management design has been to make it work in a distributed scenario. Session_End only ever fired when sessions used inproc mode (local server memory) and the .NET Core team [have stated that they won't add features that only work locally](https://github.com/aspnet/Session/issues/20).

Take a look here for managing [Application Session in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?highlight=session).

**HttpModules**

HttpModules have been replaced by middleware in ASP.NET Core and events such Application_BeginRequest or Application_EndRequest are methods of global.asax which is an Http_Module.
So, to replace those you have to write your own middleware.

I will not write that code for you but everything what you need (with code samples!) is here: [Migrating HTTP handlers and modules to ASP.NET Core middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/http-modules).

**Authenticate**

Regarding Application_AuthenticateRequest, you should also read the document about [Request features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/request-features#request-features).